# Create Excel chart with two y-axes: constant data on axis 1, dropdown list data on axis 2?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, axis, dropdownlist

Comfortable with adding a second axis to, and just learned how to use a drop-down list with, an Excel chart. Can't find anything about doing both at the same time. My example:

Calendar dates (or months) would be displayed on the x-axis and population data would display constantly on y-axis 1. Would like to display several variables, one at a time, on y-axis 2 by choosing individual variables from a drop-down list. If it makes things easier, doesn't matter if the constant y-axis is #1 or #2.

Is this possible? If so, can someone please provide a (link to a) solution? Are there other ways of doing this (other than manually Selecting Data... each time we want to look at a different variable)?

Have access to newer versions at home, but hopefully solution can be used with Excel 2010 (work limitation).

Thanks!

Comment: Well?  Have you seen my answer?  Is it useful to you?   If it is, please click on the checkmark to the left.

Answer (score 0):

Just set up a switch column that will be the one you display. 
For example, let Columns `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and `E`
be “Date”, “Population”, “Temperature”, “Humidity”,
and “Number of UFO Sightings”, respectively. 
Let some cell (I chose `K1`) be a dropdown using `C1:E1` as a list. 
Then set `G2` to be

```
=IF(K$1=C$1, C2, IF(K$1=D$1, D2, IF(K$1=E$1, E2, "")))
```

and drag down. 
Column `G` is now a mirror of Column `C`, `D`, or `E`,
based on which value is selected in cell `K1`.

Then plot Columns `A`, `B`, and `G`, and put `G` on the second vertical axis. 
Now the chart will switch immediately among Column `C`, `D`, and `E`
when you change the value in `K1`.

[image: Chart of Population and Temperature]

[image: Chart of Population and Humidity]

[image: Chart of Population and Number of UFO Sightings]